# can't pass a variable to a third activity

Tags: android-activity

I have three activities:
-login
-choice
-entry
I Must pass the var "Name" from login to choice (and this work well) and then,from choice to entry,and this is where i have the problem :/
I can pass name to choice,but when i try to pass it to entry,i can't!
This is the code to pass from login to choice

```
            Intent intent;
            String pkg=getPackageName();                    
            intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), scelta.class);
            //inseriamo i dati nell'intent
            String parts[] = risp.split("/");
            intent.putExtra(pkg+".myNome", parts[0]); 
            intent.putExtra(pkg+".myId", parts[1]);
            startActivity(intent);
```

this is choice(where probably is the error):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scelta);        
     // l'intent di questa activity
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String pkg=getPackageName(); 
    //prendiamo i dati   
    String nome=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome"); 
    String Id=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myId"); 
    intent.putExtra(pkg+".myNome", nome); 
    intent.putExtra(pkg+".myId", Id);  
    TextView tvNome =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome); 
    tvNome.setText(nome);
}


//pulsante per il checkin
public void checkin (View v){
     // l'intent di questa activity
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String pkg=getPackageName(); 
    //prendiamo i dati   
    String nome=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome"); 
    String Id=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myId"); 
    //li reinseriamo nell'intent
    intent.putExtra(pkg+".myNome", nome); 
    intent.putExtra(pkg+".myId", Id);
    intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), entrata.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

checkin is the method that I use when i tap on the button for pass from choice to entry.
And this is where i take name in Entry:

```
Intent intent=getIntent(); // l'intent di questa activity
String pkg=getPackageName();   
String nome=intent.getStringExtra(pkg+".myNome");  //prendiamo i dati

TextView tvNome =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nome); 
tvNome.setText(nome);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450658/android-cant-pass-variable-to-a-third-activity

Answer (score 0):

In your `checkin()` method you add the extras and then you create a new Intent which replaces the local "intent" variable, effectively clearing the extras again. Reorder the last 4 lines of your `checkin()` method like this:

```
intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), entrata.class);
intent.putExtra(pkg+".myNome", nome); 
intent.putExtra(pkg+".myId", Id);
startActivity(intent);
```